problema tratar de generar mi apk release flutter vscode
al momenot de tratar de hacer una apk mi consola me muestra esto :

le pase por chat gtp y me mando a arreglar el build.grade pero tampoco:


El error es en el package: flutter_windowmanager, este debe de tener un namespace, crea un fork y agregas el namespace dentro de el para que este te permita seguir tu compilación.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

si vas a compilar para release, no puede ir "com.example" en el nombre del paquete, y parece que no esta bien configurado las claves (keystore), te recomiendo leer el documento bien: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android
